# excel vba create pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, datasource, vba

I'm trying to create a pivot table in excel vba and fail to do so.

```
Range("A5").Select
Sheets.Add

Range("A5").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

DataArea = "Sheet1!R1C1:R" & Selection.Rows.Count & "C" & Selection.Columns.Count

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

Somehow my DataArea doesn't get accepted, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't get accepted"?

Comment: I get a runtime error saying that "Method 'CreatePivotTable' of Object 'PivotCache' failed".

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a pivot table with a data area of a single cell. If you walk backwards through your code to eliminate the `.Select`s, you'll see that you've got:

```
DataArea = "Sheet1!R1C1:R" & Range("A5").Rows.Count & "C" & Range("A5").Columns.Count
```

Which translates to

```
DataArea = "Sheet1!R1C1:R" & "1" & "C" & "1"
```

or

```
DataArea = "Sheet1!R1C1:R1C1"
```

If your data runs through "A5", then you'll want:

```
DataArea = "Sheet1!R1C1:R5C1"
```

but a single column of data doesn't give Excel much to pivot on...